# unsuccesful uninstalling of elementary theme

Tags: uninstall, desktop-environments, elementary

I install elementary theme on my Ubuntu 14.04 but It couldn't choose it at log in page, it wasn't there. So enter this`sudo apt-get purge elementary-os` and `sudo apt-get remove elementary-os` after that I removed every elementary name it packages on synaptic. But sometimes a window will open and is a blank white page. I know it is belongs to elementary because when I didn't connect to internet, same window open and it said can't connect to elementary site. there are still some of elementary exist on system. How to full delete elementary?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I delete elementary completly

Comment: Remove package extentions 'sudo apt-get autoremove' and reinstall 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop'

Comment: I uninstall ubuntu desktop really